# Allow overflow of child element while maintaining scrollability of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a popup inside a scrollable container. I want the popup to overflow outside the container when opened, but want the rest of the child elements on the container to remain scrollable. Adding `position: absolute` to popup will solve the issue but it will make the popup remain at the same place if the user scrolls, so I cannot do it that way.

In the attached code snippet, when you click on "open" button, the red coloured popup should flow out of the parent container (as its width is more than parent's width). But you can see that its constrained to its parent width only. You can also scroll in the container to verify the scrolling behaviour.

I would prefer a css only solution if possible.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('open');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const child = document.querySelector('.child');
  child.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="popup"></div>');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  height: 300px;
}

.popup {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <button id="open">Open</button>
    <div>other content</div>
        <div>other content</div>
        <div>other content</div>
        <div>other content</div>
        <div>other content</div>
        <div>other content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the contents of the `div` and the "other content" `div`s so that they are seperated from where the popup will be shown. Then use JavaScript to calculate the height.

```js
const other = document.querySelector('.other');
var start = 100;
const button = document.getElementById('open');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const child = document.querySelector('.child');
  child.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="popup"></div>');
  start -= 50;
  other.style.height = start + "px";
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.popup {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.other {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="other">
      <button id="open">Open</button>
      <div>other content</div>
      <div>other content</div>
      <div>other content</div>
      <div>other content</div>
      <div>other content</div>
      <div>other content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```